# No GUI with Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, gui

I no longer have a GUI with Ubuntu 13.04. I can log in and use the command line, but nothing more exotic than that.

Is there anything I can do to fix this without resorting to a full reinstallation?

Alternatively, can I upgrade to 13.10 from command line and expect everything to be fine even though there's something amiss in my current system?

Comment: Please try [How do I reset my Unity configuration?](http://askubuntu.com/q/17610) & [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](http://askubuntu.com/q/17381)

Comment: I tried unity-tweak-tool from the first link, bit I got several screenfuls of errors like (unity-tweak-tool:2321): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Error spawning command line 'dbus-launch -- autolaunch=[loads of numbers] --binary-syntax --close-stderr' : Child process exited with code 1. (Apologies for the formatting, I'm on a mobile and can't make it any more presentable)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

or

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity-2d
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins-extra
sudo apt-get update
```

then

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Open virtual terminal by pressing `ctrl+alt+F1`.Login with your username and password.
Then run the below commands,

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
sudo shutdown -h now
```

`Poweron` your pc,i hope it works.

Comment: Interesting. Cannot remove. No such file or directory. Would it make any sense to completely remove and reinstall X11, or would I just be causing more trouble for myself?

Comment: did you run `sudo service lightdm restart` command.